# Successfully imported Data Constructor not in scope?

Tags: haskell, types, import

What is going on here? I'm importing a data constructor, apparently successfully because I don't get an error, but when I try to use the constructor, I get an error saying its not in scope!

In `Test.hs`:

```
import Database.Persist (Key)

main = Key
```

Result:

```
$ ghc test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:3:8: Not in scope: data constructor `Key'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import Database.Persist (Key)
```

The above imports a type named `Key` but none of its constructors. To import the constructor `Key` of the type `Key` you need to do

```
import Database.Persist (Key(Key))
```

or just

```
import Database.Persist (Key(..))
```

to import all constructors of the given type.

Answer (score 3):

In order to import a constructor you must use the following syntax

```
import Database.Persist (Key (..))
```

Generally, when importing a type or typeclass by name only the *type* gets imported. The constructors and member functions must be imported using the `Name (..)` or `Name (Constructor)` syntax. This is fairly convenient as it's often the case that you need to write a type signature using an imported type even if you don't ever need to construct or examine values of that type.